# In VB I want to convert data from database into a view table

Tags: sql, vb.net

I already make the connection with the database, and I can get some data from the database, but I just lost the first row of data

the code is

```
If (dbrDB.Read) Then
        Label2.Text = ""
        While (dbrDB.Read)
            Label2.Text = Label2.Text + (dbrDB("LastName") + " " + dbrDB("Firstname")) + Environment.NewLine
        End While

    Else

        Label2.Text = "Color is not Found"
```

the data I want suppose to be like this

Mike Carter

Kevin Jack

Beck Johnson

Abbie Adam

Josh  Richard

---

But the result I get is

Kevin Jack

Beck Johnson

Abbie Adam

Josh  Richard

---

So I lost the first row of the data Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I think its the combination of

```
if (dbrDB.Read)
```

and

```
while (dbrDB.Read)
```

that is causing the first record to not be displayed.  Put a breakpoint on the if line and run the de-bugger on your app.  Watch the value of (dbrDB("LastName") as you step from the if to the while.

Comment: I already put the while loop out of the if, but still not works